# How to send an array from Python (client) to Java (Server)?

Tags: java, python, sockets

I am using OpenCV on my Raspberry Pi to track circular objects. Then, I want to send the coordinate and radius values in an array of floats across the LAN to the Java program

I can send strings all fine with the code I have, but I'm having trouble trying to send numerical datatypes. What is the correct process for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A meta-answer would be to use JSON, since JSON generators and parsers can be found for every major programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at BSON?  It's like JSON, but optimised for a little more speed.